# Creating subdirectory in WPF?

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

```
string path1 = @"C:\temp\";
string path2 = "";

// Create directory temp if it doesn't exist
if (!Directory.Exists(path1))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path1);
}
```

I created the above directory `temp`, but i don't konw how to create subdirectory (like `temp1`) in `temp`?

Comment: You already have the directory for path1, so just call `CreateDirectory(path1 + "[sub folder here]")`...?

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `Exists()` check.

Comment: It may be a strange thing to ask, but what exactly does this question have to do with WPF?

Answer (score 10):

You've got the basic code already, you just need to tweak it a bit. According to the documentation on [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

> Any and all directories specified in *path* are created, unless they already exist or unless some part of *path* is invalid.

So you can just specify the full path to `temp1` and use one call.

```
string path1 = @"C:\temp\";
string path2 = Path.Combine(path1, "temp1");

// Create directory temp1 if it doesn't exist
Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
```

Note that this applies any time you want to create a directory. There's nothing special about doing this in a WPF application.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the parent `CreateDirectory()` check.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, you're right. I wasn't 100% sure until I checked the docs.